# PrimeNG - How to change p-growl style

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I'm using version 4.0.1

***p-growl*** messages have **yellow** background color and **black** font color even when the *severity* message is set to ***error***.

How can I change the style of this component? The documentation doesn't seem to be up to date.
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/growl

I tried to set my style on ***.ui-growl-message*** and ***.ui-growl-container*** but nothing happens, for example:

***my-component.component.css***

```
.ui-growl-message {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must likely add one of the following before the selector:

`/deep/`

`>>>`

before the selector. If you're using the CLI then use `/deep/`, if not. Use the other.

```
/deep/ .ui-growl-message {
    color: red;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Use `::ng-deep` instead.

Comment: It works, thank you, I used `>>>` as I'm not using CLI and the docs say `/deep/` is deprecated. I also had to refresh my page cleaning the cache, don't know why it was not taking effect... did Cmd+Shift+R

Answer (score 3):

As of the moment for primeNG styling, you have to actually apply the styles in the root styles.css to override the styles of a specific Prime component using the styleClass property.

For example:

```
<p-growl [value]="registerMessages" styleClass="registerGrowl"></p-growl>
```

in styles.css:

```
.registerGrowl.ui-growl {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

}

Check your Elements in the Dev Tools of your browser to pinpoint the right CSS elements.

The use of /deep/, >>> or ::ng-deep:: is not encouraged.